# Buscar palabras dentro de otra

Tags: python

Quiero saber si han introducido un dominio o una ip.

He probado ya varias cosas:

```
addr = raw_input('Introduce la ip o el nombre de dominio: ')

addrs= [".com", ".es"]

if addr in addrs:
    print "es un dominio"

else:
    print "es una ip"
```

También:

```
if addr == ".com" or ".es"
```

Y alguna más que se me ha ocurrido. Soy muy novato con la programación, pero necesito resolver la duda para aprender. ¿Cómo podría hacer lo que quiero?

Comment: Eso se puede resolver en programación con algo llamado "Expresiones Regulares". Busca en Google sobre ese tema, es mas o menos estándar en muchos lenguajes.

Answer (score 3):

Una idea, python tiene muchas funciones para la versión 2.7 deberías darte una vuelta por su documentación para que conozcas cuáles existen.

Por ejemplo el método *find*

```
cadena = "midireccion@gmail.com"
dominios = ["gmail","hotmail"]
bandera = False # asume que no es un proveedor 

for proveedor in dominios :
    if (cadena.find(proveedor,0,len(cadena)) > 0):
       bandera = True

if(bandera):
    print "es un proveedor"
else:
    print "es un dominio" # Hacen falta más validaciones
```

Answer (score 0):

**Por qué te falla lo que tienes**: mo lo tienes ahora, estás intentando comprobar si la cadena completa se encuentra en `addrs` (es decir si es ".com" o ".es"), cuando lo que realmente quieres hacer es comprobar si esas cadenas están contenidas dentro de la cadena introducida por el usuario.

**Cómo puedes solucionarlo**: para buscar subcadenas puedes usar [`find`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=index#str.find), una función que detecta si una cadena contiene a otra, y que devolverá la posición de la primera ocurrencia de la subcadena buscada, o -1 si no se encontró.

Entonces para lo que quieres hacer:

1. Crea una variable que indicará si se encontró la subcadena e inicializa a falso.
2. Crea un bucle que atraviese los valores de `addrs` y compruebe si están en la cadena introducida por el usuario
3. Si lo están, cambia la variable del punto 1 a verdadero

El código podría ser algo así ([y lo puedes ver corriendo aquí](http://pythonfiddle.com/ejemplofind)):

```
addr = raw_input('Introduce la ip o el nombre de dominio: ')
addrs= [".com", ".es"]
encontrado = False

for valor in addrs :
    if addr.find(valor) > -1 :
        encontrado = True


if encontrado :
    print "es un dominio"
else:
    print "es una ip"
```

Aunque [como indica Toledano en un comentario](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/51617/buscar-palabras-dentro-de-otra#comment91298_51617), otra opción (más efectiva, por cierto) sería crear una expresión regular que detecte si la cadena es una IP y actuar en consecuencia.

Comment: Por que no funciona así escrito?, si se cumple el if es un dominio y si no no lo es. Cuando lo ejecuto ponga lo que ponga me lanza los dos prints.

Comment: addr = raw_input('Introduce la ip o el nombre de dominio: ')
addrs= [".com", ".es"]
encontrado = False

for valor in addrs :
    if addr.find(valor) > -1 :
        print "es un dominio"
    else:
        print "es una ip"

Comment: Porque no estás buscando la subcadena sino que estás comprobando que sean esas cadenas completas. Así por ejemplo dirá que ".com" es un dominio porque coincide completo, pero "midominio.com" te dirá que es una up

Answer (score 0):

Hola creo que es más fácil así.

la ip es un número y un dominio son letras prueba lo siguiente

```
cad=input ('Introduce la ip o el nombre de dominio: ')

try:
    aux=int(cad)
    print (cad, ": es una ip")

except:
   print (cad, ":es un dominio")
```